# Is there any way to condense multiple Where-Object conditions in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, variables, where-object

Novice scripter here and I have a script that connects to multiple file servers and recurses through directories on them looking for files over 90 days old. All that works great.

I'm using Get-ChildItem -include and -exclude to filter the files I want to report on but I also need to filter out certain directories and get-childitem can't filter directories so I'm piping the results over to a Where-Object that then compares the $_.FullName property to strings I want to exclude.

My problem is that I'm having to adjust the directory names I'm filtering for on a regular basis depending on what clients name their files and managing the script is getting a little out of hand as I have to keep adding -and ($_.FullName -notMatch "BACKUPS") conditions to the get-childitem line.

Here's my relevant code:

```
$Exclusions = ('*M.vbk','*W.vbk','*Y.vbk')
$Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -include ('*.vib','*.vbk','*.vbm','*.vrb') -Exclude $Exclusions -Recurse -File | 
         Where {($_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite) -and 
             ($_.FullName -notMatch "BACKUPS") -and 
             ($_.FullName -notMatch "Justin") -and 
             ($_.FullName -notMatch "Monthly") -and 
             ($_.FullName -notMatch "Template") -and 
             ($_.FullName -notMatch "JIMMY") -and 
             ($_.FullName -notMatch "ISAAC")}
```

I set up the $Exclusions variable to use in Get-ChildItem so that I have a single variable to adjust as needed. Is there a way to condense all the individual Where ($*.FullName -notMatch "JIMMY") entries to just use one variable like... Where ($*.FullName -notMatch $DirectoryListVariable)?

Basically I just need to make this easier to manage and change if that's possible. If not then I can just keep adding new lines but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use `Select-String` to test `$_.FullName` for multiple patterns at once: `{... -and -not($_.FullName |Select-String BACKUPS,Template,JIMMY,ISAAC -CaseSensitive)}`

Answer (score 3):

Use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) alternation (`|`) to match any one of multiple patterns:

```sh
# Array of name substrings to exclude.
$namesToExclude = 'BACKUPS', 'Monthly', 'Justin', 'Template', 'JIMMY', 'ISAAC' # , ...

# ...
... | Where-Object { 
  $_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite -and 
  $_.FullName -notmatch ($namesToExclude -join '|')
}
```

- For case-*sensitive* matching, use `-cnotmatch`
- As an alternative to defining an *array* of patterns to then [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) with `|` to form a single string (`'BACKUPS|Monthly|...'`), you may choose to define your names as part of such a single string to begin with.

  - Do note that the resulting string must be a valid regex; that is, the individual names are interpreted as regexes (subexpressions) too.
  - If that is undesired (note that it isn't a problem here, because the specific sample names are also treated literally as regexes), you can escape them with `[regex]::Escape()`.
- Finally, note that [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) and its variant perform *substring* (subexpression) matching; to match input strings *in full*, you need to *anchor* the expressions, namely with `^` (start of the string) and `$` (end of the string); e.g.
  `'food' -match 'oo'` is `$true`, but `'food' -match '^oo$'` is not (`'oo' -match '^oo$'` is).

Comment: Thank you! This is an awesome tool to add to my toolbox.